# Clip vector by extent in fiona

Tags: python, clip, fiona

I'm relatively new to fiona and I'm wondering how I can crop/clip a vector file with a bounding box. It is important to mention I want to clip, not only to get the features withing the bounding box. So on this image, the input is in orange and the highlighted area is the desired result (imagine where was the bounding box).

[image]
This is the ogr2ogr equivalent:

```
ogr2ogr -spat -0.58 0.60 0.62 -0.30 -clipsrc spat_extent /tmp/result.shp /tmp/source.shp test
```

or from QGIS processing plugin "Clip vector by extent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiona does not have spatial operations such as clipping, intersections, unions, etc.

The [user manual](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#example), "explains how to use the Fiona package for reading and writing geospatial data files. "

It states:

> There are no layers, no cursors, no geometric operations, no
>   transformations between coordinate systems, no remote method calls;
>   all these concerns are left to other Python packages such as Shapely
>   and pyproj and Python language protocols.

Having said that, if you're looking for a python solution, I suggest looking at [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) for geometric operations. The [set-theoretic](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#set-theoretic-methods) methods will have what you need. Specifically, I think [intersection](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersection) should give the results you're after.

[image]

In your example, you'll need to create an object for the orange features and another object for the bounding box.

The intersection code is simply:

```
a.intersection(b)
```

Where `a` is the orange, and `b` is the bounding box.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! Exactly what I wanted to do, I missed the part that fiona is data only.